# Where does the Raspberry Pi store its network configuration?

Tags: raspbian, networking

Its seems my Raspberry Pi's Network Preferences program stores its connections in somewhere other then /etc/network/interfaces , where exactly is that information stored at?

I was told it was in /etc/NetworkManager/, but that folder don't exist.

PS: I am using the Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian.

Answer (score 4):

It should be in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: Problem is that when I changed my static ip address via Network Preferences, there was no change in the /etc/network/interfaces file.
So it is likely also in another place, I think.

Comment: @needoriginalname Tell me about your setup. What's that you're trying to configure ? Is it wifi module or LAN ?

Comment: Wifi, Its basically a clean setup.

I already got the Wifi setup via wpa_supplicant, I had to fill that out manual as the gui does not play nicely with hidden networks.
What I want to do is still have the Network Preferences still control how the network works, but I need it to have a pre-set static IP address, and not get one from DHCP. While stilling get the other information from the DHCP.

Comment: You can't use static and dynamic address on the same interface. It sounds like you may want to look into setting up a DHCP Reservation.

Comment: Yes, reserving an IP address for a particular MAC (hardware address) is something that (some) modem/routers offer - you have to do it in the routers setup though - typically via a web-browser to the IP address of the router from a connected PC (or Pi) - which IS easier to do via a temporary wired network connection! Then allow the relevant device to use DHCP after all.

Comment: Remember MACs (and IP addresses) actually refer to the network interface NOT the Host - this can get a little confusing if you have wired and wireless devices on the same host both connected to the network.

Answer (score -4):

You can follow [these steps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypi/ug/getting-the-raspberry_pi-ip-address.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) to change the network configuration.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.